# Child rows (show extra / detailed information) with fixed columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use Datatables plugin https://datatables.net

How can I build row_details ( subtable ) https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html with left and right fixed columns https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html
Like this 
`datatables` https://jsfiddle.net/bagratzakaryan/bu9o7btL/8/
But in my case, I use server side and get an error with the datatables.js
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46536/child-rows-show-extra-detailed-information-with-fixed-columns?new=1 , see under

[image: datatable.js error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted the question in the `datatables` forum, and into this answered the question.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46536/child-rows-show-extra-detailed-information-with-fixed-columns?new=1

https://datatables.net/download/compatibility

I've solved this task like this code.

```
var dataSet = [];  // like json
var columnDefs = [];  // init data in the columns

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
    scrollX: true,
});

// datatable fixed columns
var fixedColumns = new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table, {
    leftColumns: 0,
    rightColumns: 1
});
```

> event.open details control

```
// unset fixed right column after epening additional details
fixedColumns.s.rightColumns = 0;
fixedColumns.s.iRightColumns = 0;
table.fixedColumns().update();

// hide fixed right column after epening additional details
$('.DTFC_RightWrapper').hide();
```

> event.close details control

```
// set fixed right column after closing additional details
fixedColumns.s.rightColumns = 1;
fixedColumns.s.iRightColumns = 1;
table.fixedColumns().update();

// show fixed right column after closing additional details
$('.DTFC_RightWrapper').show();
```

Link [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bu9o7btL/11/)